# Argument deduction inside function template

Tags: c++, templates

While working in some project I come across something like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const T&);
};

template <typename T>
auto bar(const T& t)
{
    return Foo(t);
}
```

How is `Foo`'s template argument deduced in this case?

Comment: It is resolved to `return Foo<T>(t);` using [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

Comment: `Foo(t)` is basically deduced as `Foo<decltype(t)>(t)`, which is equal to `Foo<T>(t)`.

Comment: @CoryKramer - You meant this link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: In the same way it is deduced when executing Foo foo { 1 };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purpose of class template argument deduction your class `Foo` will have one (implicitly generated) fictional function template overload:

```
template<class T> Foo<T> F(const T&);
```

Additionally the copy deduction guide gives the fictional overload:

```
template<class T> Foo<T> F(Foo<T>);
```

There are no user-defined deduction guides, so this set is complete. Template argument deduction and overload resolution is performed as if you were calling this `F`.

Assuming `t` is not a cv/ref-qualified `Foo<U>` for some `U`, the first template will always be chosen because the second can not be deduced.

The first overload will essentially deduce `T` as the type of `t` with ref- and const-qualifiers removed, which is also `T` from `bar` with ref- and const-qualifiers removed.

If `t` is a cv/ref-qualified `Foo<U>`, for some `U`, then `T` will be deduced to that `U` due to the second overload being preferred in function template partial ordering.

So, e.g.

```
bar(1)                    // Deduces Foo<int>
bar<const int&>(1)        // Deduces Foo<int>
bar<const int>(1)         // Deduces Foo<int>

bar(Foo<int>{1})           // Deduces Foo<int>
bar(Foo<const int&>{1})    // Deduces Foo<const int&>
```